# How to make the mosaic plots of 20 dataframes and put them in one page in r?

Tags: r, mosaic-plot, ggmosaic

I created 20 data frames in a loop already. And assigned them in the loop as below

```
for(x in 1:20){
  my_file <- read.table(paste0("file_name",x), head=TRUE) %>% 
    select(Count, Total) %>% 
    data.frame()
  assign(paste0("my_file_",x), my_file)
}
```

And I get each data frame just like this: (each data frame has the same Count names with the same sequence but the numbers are different)

```
Count  Total
 A      22
 B      31
 C      45
 D      70
```

How can I make the **mosaic plot** for each data frame and **put them on one page**, with the same **arrangement** as below?

```
Block A  Block B
Block C  Block D
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The details depend on the particular package/function you are using. If you use the base `mosaicplot()` function, you can simply employ `par(mfrow = c(..., ...))` with a suitable layout. If you are using `mosaic()` from `vcd` then you can either create your own `viewport()` with a `grid.layout()` or use the `mplot()` function for that purpose. See `example("Ord_plot", package = "vcd")` for a worked example.